# Intrinsic definition of the weight filtration

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, hodge-theory, weights, hodge-structure

Let $X$ be a smooth quasiprojective complex variety. Then Deligne (Theorie de Hodge II) defined a weight filtration on the Betti cohomology of $X$. The general philosophy is quite simple: express the cohomology of $X$ in terms of the cohomology of smooth projective varieties by compactification and resolution of singularities, and then prove the independence of the choices (of compactifications and resolutions).

Is there any known way to define the weight filtration in an intrinsic way, i.e. without making any extra choice?

In some sense the non-trivial part of the weight filtration should say something on the "behaviour at infinity of $X$". Is it possible to make this precise and to express this information without choosing an arbitrary compactification? Maybe in a analytic way: the usual Hodge decomposition for projective smooth varieties can be seen in terms of harmonic forms (let say that I allow a choice of metric), in the non-compact case, is there any relation between the weight filtration and some harmonic forms (with some appropriate growth condition)?

Comment: Regarding analysis, it does not seem to be possible: there's a standard example of $\mathbf{C}^\times\times\mathbf{C}^\times$ and the moduli space of flat $GL_1$-bundles over an elliptic curve being analytically isomorphic but having different weights in cohomology: the former one has degree 2 cohomology in weight 4 while the latter one has degree 2 cohomology in weight 2.

Comment: (I corrected the spelling in your title.)  Pavel's point is very good,
but it may not be a fatal obstruction for doing what you want. However,
you should be aware that on noncompact manifolds, the space of harmonic
forms is very sensitive to the metric. So even if this works,  you may trading one choice
for another.

Comment: You may try to read my papers on weight structures.:) If your cohomology theory factors through motives then you can define weight filtration for any cohomology of any variety (or motif, or scheme over a more general base) in terms of certain Chow-weight truncations. Yet the latter are only well-defined up to a certain "homotopy". I can tell you more if you would be interested in the subject.

Comment: I could be interested by a description in terms of algebraic cycles, so probably I would like to know what Chow-weight truncations are.

Comment: I would certainly be very glad if you would read my papers; you may try to start with the survey http://arxiv.org/abs/0903.0091 (though it is not very new). Yet (unfortunately) the matters you need are not concentrated in a single section. So you may start with having a look at section 2.2 of Lecomte, Florence; Wach, Nathalie, Réalisation de Hodge des motifs de Voevodsky,  
Manuscripta Math. 141 (2013), no. 3-4, 663–697, instead.